# The Sum of Perfect Squares

Tags: number-theory, group-theory

In Symmetry and the Monster, I ran across this interesting fact:

Let $\displaystyle f(n) = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$

Let $x$ be an integer

Then $f(n) = x^2$ for only two tuples $(n,x)$: $(1,1)$ and $(24,70)$

How would you prove this? Intuitively, is there something special about $24$?

Comment: The identity $f(24) = 70^2$ can be explained with the [Leech lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice) but it isn't clear to me how this helps proving that there is no other such identity.

Comment: It can also be found using elliptic curves, also there is an elementary proof but it is two pages of hard work.

Comment: See also: [The sum of the first $n$ squares is a square: a system of two Pell-type-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74265).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/vyuka/2010/semtc2/clanky/AnglinSquarePyramid.pdf) that proves this fact (hopefully it is accessible). Also, there just usually aren't many numbers that are more than one kind of [figurate number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number) at once, and 24 happens to be the only solution when we look for [square pyramidal numbers that are also square numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number#Relations_to_other_figurate_numbers).

Comment: Here is JSTOR link to the article: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323911