# Only $1$ and $4900$ are squares as $1+4+9+\ldots+ n^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I encountered this fact yesterday: $1$ and $4900$ are the only squares as the sum of $1+4+9+\ldots +n^2$. I was trying to solve this problem using my knowledge of elementary number theory. I reduce it to the point:

Show that $(a,b,c)=(2,5,7)$ is the only positive integer solution to
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{}
6\times a^2+1=b^2 \\
12\times a^2+1=c^2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
(then let $n=6\times a^2$, you get $4900= 24\times25\times49/6$)

I recognize these as Pell's equations, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem

Comment: This question is related: [The sum of the first $n$ squares is a square: a system of two Pell-type-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74265). You might have a look at [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/74265), too.

Answer (score 2):

You are exploring what has been called the [Cannonball problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem). Édouard Lucas formulated the cannonball problem as a Diophantine equation
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N n^2 = M^2$$
or
$$\frac{1}{6} N(N + 1)(2N + 1) = \frac{2N^3 + 3N^2 + N}{6} = M^2.$$

Lucas conjectured that the only solutions are $N=1, M=1$, and $N=24, M=70$, using either $1$ or $4900$ cannon balls (as it seems you have observed). It was not until 1918 that [G. N. Watson proved it](https://archive.org/details/messengerofmathe4849cambuoft/page/n7/mode/2up), using a method that is far beyond on the scope of elementary number theory. However it was [proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323911?origin=crossref) in $1990$ in just over $4$ pages, if you are interested in seeing a simpler proof.

Comment: The last link is broken, I think you may be logged in to an university account when copying the link.

Comment: Yes, the only place to access the paper is on JSTOR, so you need a login.

Comment: It’s not that it’s on JSTOR that’s the issue. Click on the link while in incognito mode.

Comment: If you don't have access to JSTOR, I don't know any other way to access the paper. Let me know if you find another link that doesn't require login.

Comment: The issue that the paper is found on JSTOR is NOT the issue. https://www-jstor-org.colorado.idm.oclc.org/stable/2323911?origin=crossref You linked to your universities access page. Try accessing the link on incognito, off your university wifi. It will just bring you to a ucolorado login page. I guess changing the link like this actually works: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323911?origin=crossref

Comment: Ah, gotchya. Good catch, I just changed the link.

Comment: This is why, instead of "a paper", the link text should be a proper citation with title, author's name, year, and journal name. That way, people can find the paper even if something is wrong with the link.